# Mongoose formula field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Is it possible in Mongoose to create a formula field on one model that takes data in from a related model and updates automatically when the related record changes. Say I have a todo model and a user model. On the todo, i would like to have a user_id and a user_email field. The user_email will take the email field on the related user. If the user record is changed, the user_email field will automatically be updated on the todo to reflect the change. This way, I can use my client application to query for todos with just an email address. Here are the models I had in mind:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', {
    description     : String,
    User_id         : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    isCompleted     : Boolean,
    createdDate     : Date,
    User_email      : String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', {
    name            : String,
    email           : String
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible! According to the example would be done this way.

```
User.pre('save', function(next){
    var nowDocument = this;
    User.findById( doc._id, function(err, beforeDocument){
        if(err) retrun next(err);
        // Here is to compare and modify*
        next();
    });
});
```

*To this point the data is validated.